# Magento 2 - disable sale for product by plugin or event

Tags: magento2, event-observer

The product has attribute "is_special_action". I need to disbale product for sale if this attribute equals 1.

I suspect we can use `CustomModule\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product.php` class, add this plugin to `di.xml`

But what events will used in plugin?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use plugin instead of event, Magento 2 has a method inside Product model called., `isSalable()`

When this method returns `false` then the customer is unable to buy this product online.

For e.g:

```
public function aroundIsSalable(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, \Closure $proceed)
{
    if ((bool) $subject->isSpecialAction() === true) {
        return false;
    }

    return $proceed();
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a plugin **after** the method `isSalable()` in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`

```
 public function afterIsSalable(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $result)
 {
    if ($product->getData('is_special_action')){
      $product->setData('salable',false);
      $result = false;
    }

   return $result;
}
```